# Do talents ever supersede their weaker versions?

Tags: shadow-of-the-demon-lord

Specifically, I'm looking at the sorcerer exper path. At the third level, they get the Sorcery talent, which lets them gain strain (a path-specific resource) in order to buff their spell. At level 6 they get the Greater Sorcery talent, which lets them gain strain in order to buff their spell, but better. Can sorcerers apply both of these talents to a spell, gaining 2 strain?

I suspect there are other paths with similarly upgraded talents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are not many cases of this in the core rules and the ones I can find are all straightforward in their wording except the Sorcerer. Similar talents usually expand upon the base one, but this is called out:

> Warrior:Combat Mastery: This talent is
>   **cumulative** with Combat Expertise.
>
> Rogue:Dirty Tricks/Backstab: ... the attack deals 1d6 **extra**
>   damage.

(emphasis mine)

Thus in cases like the Warlock's Expert Spell Thief and subsequent talent the omission of the word additional indicates the override:

> You can use Steal Spell twice.

In the case of the Sorcerer the Core Rulebook is indeed hazy on this. In the recently released [Paths of Power](http://schwalbentertainment.com/2017/03/13/paths-of-power/) expansion the sorcerer has received some minor changes. One of them is that now the Greater Sorcery talent explicitly states that:

> Greater Sorcery replaces the Sorcery talent.

Even if you do not have or would not like to use the expansion, I would still recommend ruling/using it this way. No other path offers you an ability that would add 3 boons to a roll to my knowledge. Sorcerers are plenty powerful with the +2 boon already.

I cannot say there is a general rule here. All the cases are handled separately, the sorcerer was just worded ambiguously.